# Foundation for Emails: Small View Port in Gmail app

Tags: gmail, zurb-foundation, html-email, email-templates

I am trying to build 2 responsive columns using Foundation for Emails like the example below.

```
<columns small="12" large="6">First Column</columns>
<columns small="12" large="6">Second Column</columns>
```

It works default Android Email app, but it doesn't on the Gmail app for Android. Gmail app seems to render the Large View Port shrank.

Comment: Are you using media queries to stack in smaller view port? Edit you post to add the media query please.

Comment: Would be good to see the all of your CSS. Failing responsiveness can sometimes point to Gmail stripping out a style block that has an error in it.

Comment: @Syfer all css is coming from Foundation for Emails. No custom css so far

Comment: @Gwesolo all css is coming from Foundation for Emails. No custom css so far

Comment: Use media queries to fix things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail App for Androids does not render Small Viewport. It shrinks Large Viewport into the screen.